# Call to a member function save() on a non-object in my example

Tags: cakephp

Db tables name:: **users, drprofiles**

Model **User,Drprofile**

I am getting error in

> $this->invoice->Drprofile->save($this->request->data);

how to proceed here

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $hassave=array(
'Work' => array(
                    'className' => 'Work',
                    'joinTable' => 'drprofiles',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',

                )
                );

    public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter();

  $this->Auth->allow('add'); 




    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            /* login and redirect to url set in app controller */
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
         /* logout and redirect to url set in app controller */
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

   public function add() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($invoice = $this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            //$this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice has been saved.'), true);
            if(!empty($invoice)) {
                $this->request->data['Drprofile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;

                $this->invoice->Drprofile->save($this->request->data);
                echo "InvoicesWork save completed?<br/>";
                echo var_dump($this->request->data);
            }
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice could not be saved.', true));
        }
    }



    }


}
```

Here before the error line, all fields are getting inserted in users table properly, but in dbprofiles table it is not getting inserted properly.

Comment: is it `Dbprofile` or `$this->invoice->Drprofile->save($this->request->data);`

Comment: i am unable to understand your statement you said you have table name `Dbprofiles` but you are joining `Drprofiles` that is why i am asking you to confirm your table name and then tell are you writting wrong table name in code or table name in database does not exist.

Comment: @NaveedYousaf  sorry my table name drprofiles

Comment: currently you are in `UsersController` and want to save data in `Drprofiles` for that you will have to load the `Drprofile` model in `Users` controller or you will use `saveAssociated` for that if they have assosciation

Answer (score 0):

invoice as in lowercase i?

call to a member function save on a non-function is usually because the model is not in the current class. so you cannot call a function from different class.

What you can do is by adding this code under your `class YourController{}`

```
public uses = array('YourModel','YourModel2');
```

What it do is it will include YourModel,and YourModel2 so that you can use it in your controller. So you can now use `$this->YourModel->save()` and `$this->YourModel2->save()`.